# Adaptive subsurface not spherical

Tags: cycles-render-engine, subdivision-surface

I have a basic cube with the adaptive subsurface modifier attached.

I am getting this in my render:

[image]

I was expecting the displacement to be more uniform over the cube.

Here is my material and other related settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the `.blend` file I used:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a one-dimensional "Fac" output from the noise texture to produce a scalar displacement.  This is interpreted as a multiple of the vector (1,1,1) and so displaces the cube along the diagonal.  Take the "Color" output of the noise texture to get a three-dimensional noise from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1) and use some Vector Math nodes to center and scale it, like so:

[image]

Alternatively, you could take your one dimensional noise and pass it to the "Height" input of a "Displacement" node to get a proper displacement output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How come your shader nodes look different to mine?

Comment: Do you mean the "Subtract" and "Scale" in the first screen shot?  Those are **Vector** Math nodes, not normal math nodes.  Do an "Add -> Converter -> Vector Math" to get them.

Comment: OK. You also have a `3D` option in your Noise Texture. Do you have some addins installed?

Comment: Wait... you can use *Displacement input* even without the *Displacement Node*? And it actually works? What kind of wizardry is this? :) Seriously sir, I've learned a lot here.

Comment: @rhughes, the dimensionality pull-down was added in 2.81 or 2.82.  In 2.80, the Noise Texture is 3D by default.